# Upload video from Android app to Youtube, Facebook, Gmail using SEND intent

Tags: android, video, upload, youtube, send

[EDIT] I'm working on Android Lollipop.  I want to share (upload) my video (.mp4) from sdcard to Facebook, Youtube,... using intent SEND. My problem is that: when I upload video first time, everything works perfectly. But if I try to upload this video again, nothing is attached. (For example: first time: I upload video to Facebook successfully. Then I try to upload it to Facebook again, video is not attached). Here is my code now:

```
     ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
     content.put(Video.VideoColumns.TITLE, "My Test");
     content.put(Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED, 
     System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
     content.put(Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
     content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, "/sdcard/rec5.mp4");

     ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
     Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,content);
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     intent.setType("video/*");     
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
     intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title");       
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share using"));
```

Can anybody tell me what did I miss in my code?

Comment: @Ravi: please read my edited post. Now problem is: I can't upload video again. If I try to upload another video, it works. But it works only one time for each video.